# how to add hover in in-line style?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styles, antd

I used Button tag from ant design and I change its color with style.
now I want to add hover color to this Button. How can I do it?

```js
export default class NavBar extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <PageHeader
          style={{
            border: '10% solid rgb(235, 237, 240)',
          }}
          title=""
          extra={[
            <Button type='link' style={{ color: "brown"}} key="1" href='/'>Home</Button>,
          ]}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are a number of mouse event props to add to components that may be helpful to you:

> onMouseDown || onMouseEnter || onMouseLeave || onMouseMove ||
>   onMouseOut   || onMouseOver  || onMouseUp

etc...
https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

i would try:

```
export default class NavBar extends React.Component{
    state={
        buttonColor: 'brown'
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <PageHeader
                    style={{
                        border: '10% solid rgb(235, 237, 240)',
                    }}
                    title=""
                    extra={[
                        <Button  
                            style={{ color: this.state.buttonColor }} 
                            onMouseEnter={()=>this.setState({ color: 'blue' })}
                            onMouseLeave={()=>this.setState({ color: 'brown' })}
                            key="1" 
                            href='/'
                            type='link'
                        >
                            Home
                        </Button>,
                    ]}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```